# How to dispatch two actions (one is async), in redux-thunk?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, infinite-loop, redux-thunk

Dispatch multiple actions in redux-thunk and receive i**nfinite loop**. 
I am trying to turn on a spinner before a request goes to the back-end and stop spinner after request succeeds or fails. 
Does anyone have any idea about where I've done mistake?

My code looks like this.

```
logic.js
```

```js
import * as actions from "./actions";

export const getData = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(actions.startSpinner());
    setAuthorizationToken(getToken());
    axiosInstance
      .get("/data")
      .then(response => {
        dispatch(actions.stopSpinner()); //I guess this is problem ?
        dispatch(actions.getData(response.data));
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        dispatch(actions.stopSpinner());
      });
  };
};
```

And file `actions.js`

```js
export const startSpinner = () => {
  return { type: actionTypes.START_SPINNER };
};
export const stopSpinner = () => {
  return { type: actionTypes.STOP_SPINNER };
};

 export const getData = data => {
  return {
    type: actionTypes.GET_DATA,
    payload: data
 };
   };
```

And reducer for it `spinner.js`

```js
import actionTypes from "../actionTypes";

export default (state = false, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.START_SPINNER: {
      return (state = true);
    }
    case actionTypes.STOP_SPINNER: {
      return (state = false);
    }
    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
};
```

And reducer for data `dataReducer.js`

```js
import actionTypes from "../actionTypes";

const defaultState = [];

export default (state = defaultState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.GET_DATA: {
      let newState = [...action.payload];
      return newState;
    }
    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Where are you calling `getData` that's inside `logic.js` ?

Comment: why not stop spinner on `.finaly(...)` ?

Comment: @ElAoutarHamza yes, I am calling it inside one of my component in `componentWillMount`

Comment: can you please create a plunker of the same, it'll help us in answering...thx

Comment: .finally() is probably the best place to end spinners as @h1b9b said. Success or fail does not matter in the logic and without duplicating your code you can stop your spinner in finally().

Comment: @devserkan
Thank you, but when I try to execute `.finally(() => {
      dispatch(actions.stopSpinner());
    });`
it still get infinite loop

Comment: Are you sure that infinite loop is because of your spinner dispatch? Without it, does your app run flawlessly?